# SLComposeViewController to post image on facebook in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk, slcomposeviewcontroller

Looks like SDK create "`iOS Photo`" by default
Instead, How can i specify new Album creation as "XXXX"
Once i successfully posted to [`facebook`] it's showing iOS album links to (http://www.apple.com/iOS)
Instead, How can specify own link to album

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
    SLComposeViewController *Facebooksheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [Facebooksheet setInitialText:@"Hellow, World"];

    [Facebooksheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [Facebooksheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in"]];

    [Facebooksheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Post Canceled :(");
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Sucessfully Post :)");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];

    [self presentViewController:Facebooksheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi! me too it's working fine but my question is how can i change the Album name? and How can i set a link to album?

Comment: I think we can't change the album name in Facebook through coding. i think so, not sure